# Html: Bullet list issue in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have list item like below with css styles as shown.

The list displays properly in Chrome and IE.

But in Firefox (v 43+), i get lists with in proper width and height.

```css
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #2d73a9;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content ul li:before {
  content: '\f0c8';
  color: #2d73a9;
  font-size: 4px;
  background-color: #2d73a9;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <ul class="submenu-cont">
    <li class="sub-menu-links">
      <a href="#">Capacitors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu-links">
      <a href="inductors.html">Inductors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu-links">
      <a href="#">Resistors</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The bullet list is not in exact square list type in firefox.

I m trying to add pseudo element for firefox something like:

/*The below element doesnt seem to show up in the inspect element especially in the firefox browser. */

I get 'No element selected' if i inspect for sub-menu-links

```
::-moz-list-bullet {
    content: '\f0c8';
    color: #2d73a9;
    font-size: 4px;
    background-color: #2d73a9;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Try adding .dropdown-content ul li **::** before { 2 colondots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the font-awesome icon set here. All you need to define the  `font-family` here.

This code is giving me perfect result in Firefox. Also, check for the other necessary icon files which are needed to bind here with correct path.

```
.dropdown-content ul li::before {
  content: '\f0c8';
  color: #2d73a9;
  font-size: 4px;
  background-color: #2d73a9;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

And if you are not using font-awesome, than `list-style-type: square;` is enough to achieve the square bullet. This property will assigned to the `li` and `::before` is not needed in that case for bullets.

Comment: Thanks @Addweb Solutions Pvt Ltd, i guess thats the fix... font-family and a bit padding adjustment did it..!

Answer (score 1):

If you want squares for bullets - just use `list-style-type: square;`
It produces perfectly square bullets, it's cross-browser compatible and there's less code.

More info: [MDN - list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

```
li {
 list-style-type: square;
 color: #2d73a9;
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #2d73a9;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
li {
 list-style-type: square;
 color: #2d73a9;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <ul class="submenu-cont">
    <li class="sub-menu-links">
      <a href="#">Capacitors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu-links">
      <a href="inductors.html">Inductors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu-links">
      <a href="#">Resistors</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `::-moz-list-bullet` won't work. It target the list bullet, and the **square** is your `content` attribute. You can try changing your `list-style-type` to `square` or using one specific style only for Firefox, you can search for [@document](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@document): `@-moz-document` should work.